# Django authentication logic

Tags: django

Where is the appropriate place to distinguish between logged in and not logged in users?

ie. Should there be separate templates for logged in and not logged in users? or one template with if/else statements?

Comment: Have you [read](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/auth/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, only small bits of the page will be different for logged in users (though this depends completely on the type of site or system you're building). So the most common situation is to do it as a conditional in the template, e.g.:

```
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
  Show this
{% else %}
  Show that
{% endif %}
```

If you wanted to distinguish in the view logic, e.g. sending different data to the template, it would be something like:

```
if request.user.is_authenticated:
  foo="bar"
else:
  foo="baz"
```